# How to get Vista SP1?

Tags: windows-vista, download, installer

I went to the download page of Microsoft to download sp1 for vista and it tells me to install it from windows updater on my laptop, but when I go onto that, it just displays an open window saying "The page failed to load". Should I just download it of the website and install it or will that stuff up my computer?

Answer (score 2):

Standalone download for Vista 64bit: [Windows Vista SP1 64Bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=874A414B-32B2-41CC-BD8B-D71EDA5EC07C&displaylang=en)

Standalone download for Vista 32bit: [Windows Vista SP1 32Bit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B0C7136D-5EBB-413B-89C9-CB3D06D12674&displaylang=en)

Edit: Forgot to add that standalone downloads are fine. I'd also recommended slipstreaming the update to create a new ISO of an install disc which already includes SP1.

[Slipstream Vista SP1](http://apcmag.com/how_to_slipstream_vista_sp1_into_your_vista_install_dvd.htm)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but yes, these are the links. The stand alone download should be absolutely fine. Any problems, edit your question and we'll try and deal with it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Better to fix first the problem of "The page failed to load".

You should:

1. Ensure that the Windows Update site is on your trusted list for the Internet zone.
2. If you have installed Stardock Blinds or Colours, uninstall them (or update to the latest version).
3. If Update still fails, using IE to go to [How do I reset Windows Update components?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058), click the `Fix it` button and follow instructions.
4. If all else fails, use the standalone SP1 installation in the hope that installing it will fix the problem (it doesn't always, and the danger is of messing up Windows on your computer).